# P tag breaks float in floated divs

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="dates-container">

</div>
<div class="info">
   <h1>Header</h1>                             
   <p class="long">Boktjänst arrangerar tillsammans med förlagen läromedelsutställningar på olika platser i Sverige.</p>                        
   <a href="#" class="icon_window">Läs mer på Boktjänst.se</a>
</div>

CSS:
.dates-container,.info {
float:left;
}

.dates-container {
width:30px;
}
```

Ok and the problem is that P is longer then container (parent container with flexible width) and    breaks float in .info block. and .info block became under the .dates-container. How to not allow to P breakes float? Example - http://jsfiddle.net/rgcsC/

**OK. I found only one sollution. Set to div.info width in %.**

Comment: Typo: <h1>Header/h1> -> <h1>Header</h1>

Comment: I don't see any elements in your code using the class `.dates-container`.

Comment: There is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/rgcsC/

Comment: Seriously, though, what is `.long` doing?

Comment: nothing. useless style. I called it just for naming in conversation. To show that it posible be  very long

Answer (score 0):

Your p tag will expand to the full width available. Try setting the width on the p tag, or floating it left.

Comment: i cant't set width, because this block is flexible. p {float:left} didn't work

Comment: Right, you'd have to float everything in the block. Sheesh lemme try this myself... I'll get back to you

Comment: Yeah, this should be working fine. Do you have a working example? You're probably overriding your floats or have some weird margin or padding properties. By simply floating both divs you should be achieving the desired result. Give us more to go on.